# Why my own css file is not loading after installation of django-cripsy-form?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I created an website using django (HTML, CSS etc). Everyithing was fine until I wanted to add a login/register form. I used django, templates. But when I installed `django-crispy-forms` my css was not loading anymore.

Only the register form looks good now but the other stuff like logo, menu, etc are ignoring my css.

That's how I loaded my css and it worked until `django-crispy-forms`

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="{%  static  'css/style.css'  %}">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="{%  static  'css/bootstrap.min.css'  %}">
```

Only below form looks good due to the django-crispy-forms package.

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<div class="container pt-5">
<form method="POST" class="form-group">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register </button>

</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the "CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK" variable in your settings.py? Also make sure you add crispy forms to your installed apps

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'crispy_forms',
]

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

Learn more about template packs [here](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

Comment: yes i did everythin. The crispy loaded perfectly but it canceled my CSS file

Comment: Your css links are still in the same file correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I didn't change their location.

Comment: I think it's because you put the bootstrap link under your css file so your styles get overridden.